# what is Line of Business ?

Tags: meaning

> Trust and relationships have always been proxies for influence.
>   Earning attention is largely based on developing authentic
>   relationships and contributing value. While forming relationships
>   with any **Line of Business** (LOB) has always been important, it may
>   be time to reassess these relationships and invest the time and
>   efforts to create deeper partnerships.
>   Your best bet is to always strive to understand what truly motivates
>   and drives **your LOB partners’ decisions**, behaviors and successes.
>   Then evaluate ways to help to amplify their efforts.

I know it means "An LOB (line-of-business) is a general term that describes the products or services offered by a business or manufacturer."
but here "LOB partners’ decisions"
it is not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LOB is jargon for the departments, divisions, or workgroups within a large organization or business "enterprise", or even for the enterprise as an integrated whole consisting of interoperating parts, with which the I.T. department (or outside consultancy) establishes a working relationship and for which it develops software or implements information-related solutions.

LOB applications is a buzzword that has been more or less been synonymous with "vertical applications" and "enterprise applications" since it first appeared on the scene in the mid 1980s.

[Here's one](https://books.google.com/books?id=MfbDrFwiARgC&pg=PA206&dq=%22line%20of%20business%20applications%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwii8ovU04vLAhVCeT4KHcHHAekQ6AEINTAA#v=onepage&q=%22line%20of%20business%20applications%22&f=false) from PC Magazine, May 1994

[image: PC Magazine, May 1994]